# Facebook Questions API: Possible to vote on behalf of the user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just discovered this API and as of today (3/2/2012) it allows you to read and create questions on behalf of the user.  But is it possible to vote on behalf of the user yet?  This seems to be the missing key piece of functionality.  Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to register a user's vote on a poll?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9524447/how-to-register-a-users-vote-on-a-poll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as here: [How to register a user's vote on a poll?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9524447/how-to-register-a-users-vote-on-a-poll/9524678#9524678)  No you cannot do it via the API for good reason, otherwise you might get rogue applications voting on behalf of their registered users!!

Comment: unfortunate. but necessary I guess.